# How to select a specific dictionary from an API request?

Tags: python, api, spotify

I am able to get a dictionary from my request function. Here's what I get:

```
{
    'collaborative': False,
    'external_urls': {
        'spotify': 'http://open.spotify.com/user/dashrif/playlist/3LEoetnegEv2Q8jdmB8TER'
    },
    'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/dashrif/playlists/3LEoetnegEv2Q8jdmB8TER',
    'id': '3LEoetnegEv2Q8jdmB8TER',
    'images': [{
        'height': 640,
        'url': 'https://mosaic.scdn.co/640/0cd0508f78c5e5f6e2b01b3009753083c7977270527f35929eff151f80bcabec17b2fb9383da342b32d7d3432ff965abb01f706ec2efc38282a11b45d088e352f19eebb53874fcdc4366ff4249da45fe',
        'width': 640
    },
    {
        'height': 300,
        'url': 'https://mosaic.scdn.co/300/0cd0508f78c5e5f6e2b01b3009753083c7977270527f35929eff151f80bcabec17b2fb9383da342b32d7d3432ff965abb01f706ec2efc38282a11b45d088e352f19eebb53874fcdc4366ff4249da45fe',
        'width': 300
    },
    {
        'height': 60,
        'url': 'https://mosaic.scdn.co/60/0cd0508f78c5e5f6e2b01b3009753083c7977270527f35929eff151f80bcabec17b2fb9383da342b32d7d3432ff965abb01f706ec2efc38282a11b45d088e352f19eebb53874fcdc4366ff4249da45fe',
        'width': 60
    }],
    'name': 'Life Playlist Vol. I: The Fuck You Getting Hype For? You Still Broke',
    'owner': {
        'external_urls': {
            'spotify': 'http://open.spotify.com/user/dashrif'
        },
        'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/dashrif',
        'id': 'dashrif',
        'type': 'user',
        'uri': 'spotify:user:dashrif'
    },
    'public': True,
    'snapshot_id': 'PCG8b/CxCfaCjX0mmFMZ3T9NUsJC1sz5MVAXfQf3aefQhcAi4Zdm2k+3rySb/HLw',
    'tracks': {
        'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/dashrif/playlists/3LEoetnegEv2Q8jdmB8TER/tracks',
        'total': 63
    },
    'type': 'playlist',
    'uri': 'spotify:user:dashrif:playlist:3LEoetnegEv2Q8jdmB8TER'
}
```

At least I hope this is a dictionary. Honestly at this point I've gotten so many errors I'm not too sure. Here's the code in question:

```
playlist_api_endpoint = "{}/playlists".format(profile_data["href"])
playlists_response = requests.get(playlist_api_endpoint, 
headers=authorization_header)
playlist_data = json.loads(playlists_response.text)
display_arr = [profile_data] + playlist_data["items"] 
return render_template("index.html",sorted_array=display_arr)
```

Basically I want to be able to filter out the last uri object and any other uri objects when adding new playlists. I've tried .items(), filtered dictionary, and a couple of other things I can't remember. If anyone has an idea of where I'm going wrong or how to to achieve my goal, I'd love some help. Thanks!

Comment: `playlist_data['tracks']['href']`

Comment: I get KeyError: 'tracks'. Is there another way I should go about it? Thanks

Comment: I couldn't manage to reproduce your issue (check out this [trinket](https://trinket.io/python/379047bc8c) for a demo). You should try to print the content of `playlists_response.text` and `playlist_data`. Also the JSON in your question is invalid (double quotes instead of single quotes, False/True should be false/true) but I assume it's a formatting issue